Spring Boot Logging Error when running the tests
I have a spring boot project that uses lombok @Sl4fj, and when I run the tests individually using the IDE (Intellij) they pass, but when running mvn clean verify I keep getting this error:

NullPointer Cannot invoke "org.slf4j.Logger.error(String, Object, Object)" because "com.my.package.MyClass.log" is null

I am using this version of lombok:
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>

It looks like there is no implementation of a logging framework available when running the tests, but when running mvn dependency:tree
I can see:
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.5.6:compile

To me it looks like at least there should be a logback implementation when running the tests.
Edit: I just removed the mockito-inline capability by deleting the mockito-extensions folder and this particular error went away. Something tells me that lombok and mockito-inline are crashing here.

Show that class which has the errro, also show your full pom file etc.?
